# How do I produce more even output with a 6V Joule Thief?

Tags: led, boost, led-driver, joule-thief

For my 6V Joule Thief, it starts out too bright, and gets too dim towards the end of its battery life (about 3V). How can I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feedback can be used to stabilize the output, making a power supply proper rather than directly driving the LEDs with AC as in the classic JT circuit:

[image]

Source: my site, [Blocking_Oscillator_Supply.png | Seven Transistor Labs](https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/tmoranwms/Circuits_2010/Blocking_Oscillator_Supply.png)

Component values are left somewhat ambiguous as it depends on the voltage and current.  For 6V, the coupled inductor should have a 2:1 turns ratio or thereabouts (i.e. 3V peak base drive), and there is enough headroom say to turn the left PNP into a current source proper.  Any general-purpose PNP will do.  The NPN, 2N4401 is fine for lower currents, or PBSS303NX or similar for higher currents (upwards of several amperes peak).  The 10µF should be ceramic, or several in parallel at higher currents.

Similar feedback schemes can be employed to regulate current into an LED string, or jointly regulate voltage and current to provide an overvoltage limit (in case the LEDs go open circuit).  That might look like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2uGqr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Component values adjusted to... well, it runs in CircuitLab.  I absolutely would not recommend trying to do real design here; this circuit needs more accurate part models, and a more nuanced solver would also be welcome.  LTspice and breadboarding are recommended.

Assuming this would be a hand-held device with short if any wires, practically no EMC considerations are necessary.  Vin probably should have a bypass capacitor (comparable size to the output capacitor, or several times larger if electrolytic), particularly for "softer" battery chemistry like dry-cell.  Li ion* for example, typically has enough capacitance not to mind pulsed loads like this, and you would merely keep lead length short for functional purposes.

*Mind, if you do use Li ion, ONLY use with a cell/pack that includes an under-voltage protection function; this circuit will gladly over-discharge a bare cell to dangerous levels.

Comment: I have steered away from this kind of regulation to try to avoid its 5%-10% loss of efficiency in these circuits, and will attempt to perform a similar regulation using a microcontroller and a digital potentiometer to get constant power with a slight fall to output as an indicator of remaining battery life and better efficiency as well. The micro would also help do UVLO for Li-ion (thanks for the warning).

Comment: I was thinking of including alkaline(s?) with a small joule-thief to prop up Li-ions that hit bottom to keep them safe (in storage, for instance), and a latching relay to truly turn off all leakage sources, and using unprotected cells if doing that (but having the protection something I can engage on demand).

Comment: I can think of a lot of alternatives to a whole MCU to accomplish that... One, if you don't mind adding two transistors, a diff pair can sense current with sub-Vbe drop.

Answer (score 1):

### Pre-Summary

We will run an experimental simulation showing that replacing the 1K resistor of a Joule Thief with a constant current source will produce more even brightness over the life of the cells -- more linear proportional to the falling voltage.

---

### Discussion

The current through the resistor R1 and NPN-base (basically a P-N diode, about 0.6V forward voltage drop) is a function of the voltage V1.  The current through the NPN-C-E collector-emitter junction is also a function of the voltage V1. But because of the amplification of the transistor, these two are multiplied together, making the output exponential, a function of V1*V1 or V1^2.

If you replace the R1 resistor with a constant current source, then you take away the V1 term that's on the base, which brings the output back from being proportional to V1*V1, and makes it more linear, proportional to just V1.

Of course no constant current source is perfect, and this one still has a dependency on V1, but it is not as strong.

---

### Circuit # 1

Here is a fairly standard Joule Thief, modified for this study. The resistor R2 will be replaced with a constant current source, then both outputs will be matched at 5 volts, and graphed on the same graph to compare them. Here is the first circuit:

[image]

---

### Circuit # 2

Here is the second circuit, with resistor R2 replaced with a constant current source, with outputs matched at 5 volts:

[image]

---

### The Results

This does show some improvement, but not as much as I had hoped. You should see that the Constant Current curve is flatter, more of a straight line. The R2 curve is significantly steeper, and has a slight curve to it, which is the exponential effect (I expected it to be more than this).

[image]

### The Numbers

[image]

### Summary

To round up, replacing the standard 1K Joule Thief with a constant current source (more effective with a 3V or higher Joule Thief) gives a more even light output over the life of the batteries.

### Better Joule Thief

By the way, a higher voltage Joule Thief is better than the original, because it recovers more energy from the dying cells (or supercapacitor). The limiting factor is the NPN base-emitter junction which needs 0.6V to conduct much current at all, but you divide that over the four AA cells 0.6 / 4 = 0.15, so I expect this 6V Joule Thief to run its cells down to 0.15V.

### Watch Out For Corrosion, Leaking, and Popping

Just be careful -- cells taken that low are more likely to leak, corrode, and even "pop" as they release, not magic smoke, but their alkaline liquid, which is corrosive. I have not yet figured what to do about this problem.

Comment: Or their acidic liquid, if they're zinc-carbon "heavy-duty" cells rather than alkaline. Or whatever the electrolyte is in lithium primary cells; that's probably corrosive too.

Comment: @Hearth Dry cells are ammonium chloride, neutral; the MnO2 black stuff is likely the stronger health concern (just don't eat it or make dust). Lithium cells vary, but can include flammable organic carbonates, and toxic and corrosive thionyl chloride.